# How do I enable a user to share my URL to their stream in Google+ (Plus)?

Tags: google-plus

Does anyone know if there is anything available to enable the sharing of a URL to my stream in Google+ much like the options in Facebook or Twitter?

I have found [documentation on how to +1](http://www.google.com/intl/en/webmasters/+1/button/index.html), but nothing on how to share to a stream. Is there anything available yet that anyone has come across?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The +1 button now allows users to share URLs to their stream: http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/08/doing-more-with-1-button-more-than-4.html

Comment: Thanks, still quite not a share URL as per Facebook/Twitter though but the first steps towards it.

Comment: More information released today at http://googleplusplatform.blogspot.com/, certainly seems to be coming more readily now.

Answer (score 0):

Google+ now has a range of Share buttons, a Share bookmarklet and a custom URL Share Link which are documented here: https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/share/

These all allow users to manually share your content to their stream.